# How to list all files of a given folder (recursively through sub-folder)?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm writing a microsoft word macro and having difficulty with vb.net. Please help.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/730510/11738627) is the best solution, much faster than using FSO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729636/any-function-for-listing-out-all-the-files-of-a-specified-type-in-a-folder-in-vb6) - VB6 is almost identical to VBA.

- You will need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime if you want to [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729636/any-function-for-listing-out-all-the-files-of-a-specified-type-in-a-folder-in-vb6/729844#729844) `FileSystemObject`
- Or you can just [drop in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729636/any-function-for-listing-out-all-the-files-of-a-specified-type-in-a-folder-in-vb6/734816#734816) the CDirDrill class which means you won't need any external references.

Comment: so what you're saying is this is that this question is a duplicate of others on this site, only the others have answers...

Comment: No that's not what I'm saying. This question is about VBA. The answers to the other questions are for VB6 and cannot all be used directly in VBA. For instance *"You will need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime if you want to use `FileSystemObject`"*

Answer (score 2):

A Word Macro is usually written in VBA rather than VB.Net, I'm assuming that you meant VBA?

Use the `FileSystemObject` to access the filesystem and then use recursion to "walk" down. Here's a sample:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/File-Path/RecursiveSearchusingtheFileSystemObjectModel.htm

If it's actually VB.Net you're using, the idea will be the same but use `System.IO.Directory` rather than the `FileSystemObject`.

Comment: It's VBA indeed. Thank you 'ho'.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the FileSystemObject approach.  i normally set up a recursive search function like the one found [here](http://vba-tutorial.com/recursive-directory-regex-file-search/) and have never had any problems.