# Excel VBA: How to Read file names of type PDF and spit them into a column on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

In Excel 2003 is there any way to read pdf file names from a **single** directory and put them inside an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: You'll need to give a lot more details.  Do you want to read these filenames out of one specific directory?

Comment: yes 1 directory, very good point. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim c as Range, tmp  
Dim FolderPath as string

FolderPath = "C:\MyFolder\" 
Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

tmp = Dir(FolderPath & "*.pdf")
Do While tmp<>""
  c.value = tmp
  set c = c.offset(1,0)  
  tmp=Dir()
Loop
```

Tim

Comment: +1 I guess some of us just get it the first time. Thanks a bunch I did not know it was that easy.

Answer (score 0):

To list files from a folder take a look at [FileSystemObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713838/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-given-folder-recursively-through-sub-folder).

Provide os more info about what you need, we'll help you better.

Rgds