# reading and writing a csv file using FileSystemObject

Tags: vba, csv, filesystemobject

Is it possible to read and write csv files using FileSystemObject in VBA?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It certainly is.

Basic syntax such as

```
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    'create a csv file
    Set objTF = objFSO.createtextfile("C:\test\myfile.csv", True, False)
    'open an existing csv file with writing ability
    Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\test\myfile.csv", 8)
```

will create/open a `CSV` with `FSO`.

The `CSV` can then be modified by writing to it

While this is an Excel example you can use the same technique to write records from Outlook, Access, Word etc

```
Const sFilePath = "C:\test\myfile.csv"
Const strDelim = ","
Sub CreateCSV_FSO()
    Dim objFSO
    Dim objTF
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim strTmp As String
    Dim lFnum As Long

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set objTF = objFSO.createtextfile(sFilePath, True, False)

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'test that sheet has been used
        Set rng1 = ws.UsedRange
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            'only multi-cell ranges can be written to a 2D array
            If rng1.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                X = ws.UsedRange.Value2
                'The code TRANSPOSES COLUMNS AND ROWS by writing strings column by column
                For lCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
                    'write initial value outside the loop
                    strTmp = IIf(InStr(X(1, lCol), strDelim) > 0, """" & X(1, lCol) & """", X(1, lCol))
                    For lRow = 2 To UBound(X, 1)
                        'concatenate long string & (short string with short string)
                        strTmp = strTmp & (strDelim & IIf(InStr(X(lRow, lCol), strDelim) > 0, """" & X(lRow, lCol) & """", X(lRow, lCol)))
                    Next lRow
                    'write each line to CSV
                    objTF.writeline strTmp
                Next lCol
            Else
                objTF.writeline IIf(InStr(ws.UsedRange.Value, strDelim) > 0, """" & ws.UsedRange.Value & """", ws.UsedRange.Value)
            End If
        End If
    Next ws

    objTF.Close
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\test\myfile.csv", 8)`  that line always made a **70 - Permission Denied** error, no matter what folder I chose. It worked after I removed the line.

Comment: no, it was when i was trying to create it for the first time

Answer (score 3):

It seems possible.

> The FileSystemObject (FSO) provides an API to access the Windows filesystem, providing access to files, drives, text streams etc. The FSO is embedded within the Microsoft Scripting run-time, and is available to stand-alone applications (coded using Visual Basic, for example), to web page designers using VBScript or JScript and to users of Microsoft Office applications using Visual Basic for Applications (VBA).

Some references:-

[Using The FileSystemObject With VB and VBA](http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/fso1.html)

[How do I use FileSystemObject in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3236348/500725)