# Pull single records from csv file into excel

Tags: excel, csv, large-data

I have a 2 gig csv file that I want to read into an excel vba macro process one record at a time, or one datum at a time.  How can I?  Can I?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` to do that:

As a sample of how you can read in a file line by line:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\FSO\ServerList.txt", 1)
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
       strLine = objFile.ReadLine
       ... You code here ...
    Loop
objFile.Close
```

Just remember to add a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (where the FileSystemObject is)

[How do I use FileSystemObject in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba)