# VBA code to search substrings in a file and print the entire word

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to have a VBA code to print the entire word for a searched substring for multiple files in a location on a excel sheet?

Suppose,

- I have 10log files in location `'C:\Logs'`
- In each log file I want to search for strings listen in sheet 1 (in rows)

Eg.

```
    1]Red
    2]Blue
    3]Green

(where 1,2,3 are row numbers)
```

- Suppose the substring `Red` is found in first log file `log1.txt` in the word `Red2312`
- I want `Red2312` to be printed to the next excel sheet
- So, the output will be,

> ```
> 0] A  B  C |
>
> 1] Red2312 | log1.txt
>
> 2] Blue2121 | log1.txt
>
> 3] Red1234 | log7.txt
> ```

Any help would be great! Even how to go ahead with it..

Comment: Have a look at this: [How do I find a specific string in one of many text .log files using VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17861992/3042759)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find a specific string in one of many text .log files using VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860618/how-do-i-find-a-specific-string-in-one-of-many-text-log-files-using-vba)

Comment: Are they actual ".log" files - or Excel workbooks that you are referring to as  "log files" ?