# VBA 03 - Application Path - get to Parent Folder

Tags: excel, vba

Application: Excel

```
Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\") - 1)
```

I need to go back at least 2 Folders from the Workbook Path.

I **cannot** use Paths like "C:/Folder1", because the Application will be moved multiple times.

Comment: What is the workbook is placed at "C:\" or "C:\Temp" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `FileSystemObject` provides the method [`GetParentFolderName(path)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/getparentfoldername-method).

See [How do I use FileSystemObject in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3236348/1164465)

### Example

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim strParent As String

strParent = fso.GetParentFolderName(Me.Range("A1").value)
```

Comment: Also works in Access. Just remember to add a Reference to the  `Tools / References / Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

Answer (score 17):

Like this:

```
Function getParentFolder2(ByVal strFolder0)
  Dim strFolder
  strFolder = Left(strFolder0, InStrRev(strFolder0, "\") - 1)
  getParentFolder2 = Left(strFolder, InStrRev(strFolder, "\") - 1)
End Function


Dim strFolder
strFolder = getParentFolder2(ThisWorkbook.Path)
```

We here cut twice \subdir pattern...