# VBA Dir function not working on Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, dir

I mapped an intranet location using the File Explorer. i.e. mapped http://intranet.XXXXXXX.com/mydir/ to M:\

I'm using the `Dir` function to test if a file is present in that location:

```
 Dim FileExists as Boolean

 FileExists = Dir("M:\myfile") <> ""

 If FileExists Then MsgBox "File found in M:"
```

I run that macro on Excel 2007 and it Works Fine. When I run it on Excel 2010 though, `Dir("M:\myfile")` always returns "", even if the file is present in the specified location. I can´t find a solution that will work on both Excel versions. Any ideas?

Comment: look at [FileSystemObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba) instead. Way more intuitive than the silly `dir` function

Comment: it should be `Dir("M:\myfile\") ` NOT `Dir("M:\myfile") `

Comment: @Qbik's comment is not relevant for files but IS important for using the Dir() function to list files in directories -- on Windows, you need to include the trailing backslash (`Application.PathSeparator`), even though the trailing forward slash is optional on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

You may add file extension as a wildcard character at the end of filepath. I gave a try in excel 2010 and it worked for me.

```
  Dim FileExists As Boolean
    FileExists = Dir("D:\myfile" & "*.txt") <> ""

    If FileExists Then MsgBox "File found in M:"
```

Comment: Thanks Santosh. In fact instead of "myfile" I have the full name and extension of the file I'm trying to find. I does not work on that mapped unit M:   =   http://intranet.XXXX.com/mydir/

Comment: Forgot to say that the original macro works for any other drive like C:\ or even mapped network units.

Comment: @user3366899 The dirve you are trying to access, Is it citrix enviornment ?

Answer (score 2):

I found that if I use the full network name, it works first go. This wasn't just in VBA, but also some shortcuts also - they returned "File could not be found".

Changing from the mapped shortcut, e.g.

```
Y:\Projects\Proj1\File1.xlsx
```

to the full mapped path, e.g.

```
\\server\Department\Projects\Proj1\File1.xlsx
```

Fixed the problem

Comment: This will not work with IP  \\10.254.0.10\SomeDir type of maped servers. Neither on internet  names \\server-name.com\SomeDir

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use FSO to do what you want:

```
Option Explicit

Function test_it()
    'Test the Function - must pass the file path and name
    Debug.Print Does_File_Exist("C:\temp\form1.txt")
End Function

Private Function Does_File_Exist(sFullPath) As Boolean
' Will return True or False if file exists.
' Provide the fully qualified path and file name.
' You can disable the MsgBox displays after testing

Dim oFs         As New FileSystemObject
Dim oFile       As File

    Set oFs = New FileSystemObject
    If oFs.FileExists(sFullPath) Then
        Does_File_Exist = True
        MsgBox "Found file: " & sFullPath
    Else
        Does_File_Exist = False
        MsgBox "File not found: " & sFullPath
    End If

    Set oFs = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I'm a newbie in VBA for Excel. I copy-pasted your code in VBA and just changed the path. Then I created a macro to call the function. I get an error on the first line Option Compare Database   ("expected Text or Binary"). Seems to me that your code is not for VBA for Excel, is it?