# VBA loop through directory

Tags: vba, loops, excel, directory

**Hi All,

I would to incorporate into the below script the ability to search through files and export ONLY the data from the most recent file in folder. I will be adding a new file every week into folder so do not want the old data range to be copied across.

Can someone please help?**

---

```
Sub loopthroughdirectory()
Dim myfile As String
Dim erow
fileroot = "C:\Users\ramandeepm\Desktop\consolidate\"
myfilename = Dir("C:\Users\ramandeepm\Desktop\consolidate\")

Do While Len(myfilename) > 7

    If myfilename = "zmaster.xlsm" Then
      Exit Sub
    End If

    myfile = fileroot & myfilename
    Workbooks.Open (myfile)
    Range("range").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow,       4))

    myfilename = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: See here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/GetFileName.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278516(v=office.15).aspx) it can be done using the [`.DateLastModified`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251660(v=office.15).aspx) property. The below code should get you started:

**Untested**

```
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
Dim objFile As File
Dim myFolder
Dim strFilename As String
Dim dtFile As Date

'set folder location
Const myDir As String = "C:\Users\ramandeepm\Desktop\consolidate"

'set up filesys objects
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(myDir)

'loop through each file and get date last modified. If largest date then store Filename
dtFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
    If Len(objFile.Name) > 7 Then
        If objFile.DateLastModified > dtFile Then
            dtFile = objFile.DateLastModified
            strFilename = objFile.Name
        End If
    End If
Next objFile
Workbooks.Open strFilename
```

**Note:** This code is looking for the most recent *modified* date. So this will only work if the newest file was created *after* any modifications in other files in the folder. Also, you may need to [enable the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba).