# How to loop through similar object in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, userform

I have a userform in VBA that has some pictures. I need to loop through 15 pictures that have names like:

> imm1, imm2, ...,imm15

And I create the paths for the pictures:

```
dir1 = "c:\..\pi1.jpg"
...
dir15 = "c:\..\pi15.jpg"
```

I'd like to create a loop like:

```
    For i = 1 To 15
    (imm & i).Visible = True
   (imm & i).Picture = LoadPicture(dir & i)
    Next i
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Please use [FSO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3233203/380384) to combine paths and filenames instead of `&`. More details [here](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/filesystemobject-in-vba/)

Answer (score 1):

You can reference each image using it's name in the `Controls` property of the userform like so:

```
Public Sub VisibleImages()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 15
    Me.Controls("imm" & i).Visible = True
Next i

End Sub
```

Note: You may need to change `Me` to the name of the userform if the procedure is to be used outside of the userforms code module.

Comment: Thank you for your suggesting. Anyway later I need to create a loop like: `im1.Picture =  LoadPicture(dir1)
im2.Picture = LoadPicture(dir2)
im3.Picture = LoadPicture(dir3)
im4.Picture = LoadPicture(dir4)
im5.Picture = LoadPicture(dir5)
im6.Picture = LoadPicture(dir6) `   So I need also loop (dir & i)

Comment: Update your question with the full question. The answer I provided addresses what you asked but if you require more, you'll need to update it.

Comment: Sorry, I tought that there were an answer for both of my problems, I have updated

Answer (score 1):

I quite like this syntax:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cCont As Control

    For Each cCont In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(cCont) = "Image" And VBA.Left$(cCont.Name, 3) = "imm" Then
           cCont.Visible = True
           cCont.Picture = LoadPicture("c:\..\pi" & VBA.Right$(cCont.Name, Len(cCont.Name) - 3) & ".jpg")
        End If
    Next cCont
End Sub
```

Comment: I was going to take this approach in my answer but from the code posted, the code is targeting specific images (prefixed with `imm`) rather than every image in the userform

Comment: I've updated it to get `imm` prefixes only and load the relevant picture.