# Tracking files and file changes in excel

Tags: excel, vba

At my place of work we have recently started to utilize Excel to track the receipt, processing, and authorization of faxes through a program called RightFax. When we receive the fax we enter the time received, fax number, and who the fax has been assigned to.

Throughout the day we monitor the end folder to see what faxes have been processed (and who they were approved by, if need be) and update them accordingly in the spreadsheet. Depending on the number of faxes this can be a lengthy amount of time. Since all of the faxes follow a standard naming scheme, Excel could be used to determine what each file name should be but could it then search for these files as well to detect where they are located on our shared drive? That is to say, could Excel tell me if a fax was waiting to be processed in the processor's folder, waiting for authorization in the auth folder, or done in the end folder?

In addition to this, is there any way to tag the files in a way that Excel could read to show who authorized them rather than having to open up each individual one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use "Track Changes" in excel to see who did what to the workbook. Review>>Track Changes

Instead, you could also use VBA to capture the username of the individual that opened the sheet or made a change to a specific tab. GetUserName function: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161394  Running VBA when the workbook is open: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/auto-run-macros.htm

As for keeping an eye on the faxes in each folder... that could be done by Excel as well through VBA, but it would be a little messy and probably prone to errors here and there since it's not really the best piece of software for such a thing. If you want to go there: Check out the FileSystemObject: [How do I use FileSystemObject in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba/3236348#3236348)