# Code to Skip the File Extension While hyperlink the Files

Tags: excel, vba

The results include the file extension also which I don't want displayed. How do I drop the file extension from the text?

```
Sub mymacro()
Dim objcreate As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object, i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("C1")


Set objcreate = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = objcreate.GetFolder(rng)
i = 0

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
'select cell
Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)).Select
'create hyperlink in selected cell
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
objFile.Path, _
TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `LEFT` function to cut off the last four characters `TextToDisplay:=LEFT(objFile.Name, LEN(objFile.Name) - 4)`

Comment: it wont work if the extension's length is not 3.
Your code will fail if the extension is of length 2, or 4 or anything else than 3. In this particular scenario, if the extension is of length 3, it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways. Something like this has already been answered earlier : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27924854/6151782

I will try to handle it in different way, using split. Have a look at code below:

```
Sub mymacro()
Dim objcreate As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object, i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("C1")


Set objcreate = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = objcreate.GetFolder(rng)
i = 0

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
'select cell
Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)).Select
'create hyperlink in selected cell
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
objFile.Path, _
TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
tmpArr = Split(TextToDisplay,".")

Dim finalTextToDisplay
tmpArr = split(TextToDisplay,".")
finalTextToDisplay = ""

'considering there might be a dot in the file name itself, we will take the string till the last dot using loop
    loopLimit = UBound(tmpArr)
    for j=0 to loopLimit-1 
    if i = 0 then
            finalTextToDisplay = tmpArr(j)
    else
        finalTextToDisplay =tmpArr(j) & "." & finalTextToDisplay
    end if

    Next
i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

In above code I looped till i encounter the last dot. And to avoid a already trailing dot, I had to put an if condition so that it would not append a dot with a blank finalTextToDisplay (for the first iteration it would be empty). 
You can also start the loop from 1 and set the value in finalTextToDisplay before loop to avoid the if condition.