# Find files in different folders and gather info from them

Tags: vba, excel

I am starting a project that does the following:

I need to push a button in the current worksheet and it searches all files (with a certain name structure e.g file_date.xls) in all folders within a specific directory. I then need to pull specific numbers from the files (for example find a cell called 'title' and take the cell underneath it). All this info then gets placed in the current workbook in a table.

Basically its searching all files in all folders with a certain name and then taking specific data and putting it in a table in the current worksheet.

I am just looking for ideas/examples on what to look at and where to go with it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. it will be difficult to code every thing for you and SO don't provide Code development service. Please start coding and and search in SO for related code if required. Your list of actions are pretty clear. Go ahead by coding step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at the Scripting.FileSystemObjects first to see if this is good enough for your requirements.

[How do I use FileSystemObject in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba)

Chances are its what you want.