# Outlook Saving Attachment with Subject Name

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a Macro that saves all attachments from emails in my inbox to the directory specified. However, I would like to save the attachments with the email subject as the filename.

This is my first Macro and first time looking at VBA so any pointers are much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Outlook_VBA_Save_Attachment()
    ''Variable declarions
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim inb As Folder
    Dim itm As MailItem
    Dim atch As Attachment

    ''Variables Initialization
    Set ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set inb = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    File_Path = "H:\Notes\"

    ''Loop Thru Each Mail Item
    For Each itm In inb.Items

    ''Loop Thru Each Attachment
        For Each atch In itm.Attachments
            If atch.Type = olByValue Then
               atch.SaveAsFile File_Path & atch.FileName
            End If
        Next atch
    Next itm

    '''''Notify the Termination of Process
    MsgBox "Attachments Extracted to: " & File_Path
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is change one line:

```
atch.SaveAsFile File_Path & itm.Subject
```

To include the original file extension, you can use the FileSystemObject to grab it.  The modified code would be as follows:

```
Private Sub Outlook_VBA_Save_Attachment()
    ''Variable declarions
    Dim ns As Namespace
    Dim inb As Folder
    Dim itm As MailItem
    Dim atch As Attachment
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject

    ''Variables Initialization
    Set ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set inb = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    File_Path = "H:\Notes\"
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ''Loop Thru Each Mail Item
    For Each itm In inb.Items

    ''Loop Thru Each Attachment
        For Each atch In itm.Attachments
            If atch.Type = olByValue Then
               atch.SaveAsFile File_Path & itm.Subject & "." & fso.GetExtensionName(atch.Filename)
            End If
        Next atch
    Next itm

    '''''Notify the Termination of Process
    MsgBox "Attachments Extracted to: " & File_Path
End Sub
```

This will require a Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: That does work, so thank you, however it removes the file extension. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I modified the code sample to include the file extension.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks for the help. For future users this is how you enable reference to MS Scripting Runtime. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba

Comment: Keep in mind that if there are multiple attachments, you will only get the last one since you always overwrite the attachments. A better solution would be to combine the subject and the attachment file name: atch.SaveAsFile File_Path & itm.Subject & " - "  & atch.FileName,. You also need to make sure there are no invalid (for a file name) characters, such as ":".