# Copy and paste a file through access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to check a folder for a file, if it exists delete it an replace it with an updated version, or if the file doesn't delete then it will copy the file from a path into the individuals personal drive

**My Code:**

```
Dim FileExistsbol As Boolean
Dim stFileName As String
Dim CopyFrom As String
Dim CopyTo As String

stFileName = "H:\Test File.txt"
stFileName = Trim(stFileName)
FileExistsbol = dir(stFileName) <> vbNullString

If FileExistsbol Then
 Kill stFileName
 CopyFrom = "J:\Test File.txt"
 CopyTo = "H:\"
 FileSystemObject.CopyFile CopyFrom, CopyTo
Else
 CopyFrom = "J:\Test File.txt"
 CopyTo = "H:\"
 FileSystemObject.CopyFile CopyFrom, CopyTo
End If
```

**What Happens:**

The code executes and deletes the existing file as expected, but it appears to be failing on the copy and paste part.

**Error:**

The debug that comes up is:

> Object Required

Comment: I haven't done this for a while...you might need to create (dim) the FileSystemObject object first?

Comment: As simple as that - It worked, thank you very much.

Comment: No prob. I'm going to add some code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bare bones:

```
Dim fso As Object       'filesystemobject    
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
fso.CopyFile strSourcePathWithFileAndExt, strDestPathWithFinalBackslash    
Set fso = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said which line is throwing the error, but I noticed that you don't seem to have instantiated a new FileSystemObject:

```
dim fso as Object
set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

then use the fso reference to copy your file

```
fso.CopyFile CopyFrom, CopyTo
```

The method above used "Late binding" to interrogate the registry for `Scripting.FileSystemObject`

You can also use early binding and reference the Microsoft Scripting Runtime directly and avoid the use of `CreateObject`

This is detailed in this Stack Overflow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3236348/491557