# Looping through the same directory multiple times using a function

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing issues with  VBA's looping through a list of files in a directory.

I need to loop through files which only have the word CITIES in the file name. But some times some files with the word CITIES might have a corresponding FINANCE file and hence I have to loop through the Folder again to find the finance file and extract information from it. I have written a funtion to get the file name if it exists and the  biggest issue is the `myFile = Dir` which doesn't work as i hoped it would.  I have the code which is here.

```
Sub getTheExecSummary()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog


'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

myPath = "C:\Users\MORPHEUS\Documents\Projects\"

myExtension = "*CITIES*.xls"

myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Debug.Print myFile

Do While Len(myFile) > 0
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    Dim prntStr As String

    prntStr = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) & " (n= " _
        & wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(12, 3) & ")"

    Dim LookUpStr As String
    LookUpStr = wb.Name

    replaceStr = Left(LookUpStr, 10)

    LookUpStr = Replace(LookUpStr, replaceStr, "")


    Dim DoesTheFIleexist As String
    DoesTheFIleexist = fileLoation(myPath, LookUpStr)

    If (Len(DoesTheFIleexist) > 0) Then
        Debug.Print (DoesTheFIleexist)
    End If

    Workbooks("ExecutiveSummary.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = myFile

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Get next file name
    Debug.Print myFile
    myFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub



Function fileLoation(filePath As String, LookUpStr As String) As String
    Dim financeStr As String
    Dim myFile1 As String
    financeStr = "*FIN*.xls"
    myFile1 = Dir(filePath & financeStr)

    Do While Len(myFile1) > 0
         Debug.Print ("")
         Debug.Print (myFile1)
'        If InStr(myFile1, LookUpStr) > 0 Then
'            fileLoation = myFile1
'        Else
'            fileLoation = ""
'        End If
        myFile1 = Dir
    Loop
End Function
```

The issue is that when the `myFIle1 = Dir` in the function finishes executing, the original `myFile = Dir` also is at its end (at least I think it is)

Comment: The function Dir uses global variables internally, hence you cannot nest it into another Dir.
Suggestion: Loop for Cities while collecting Finance in an array or collection. Then loop through the collection of Finance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way around this issue, that's just how the `Dir` Function works.

Instead, look into using a [FileSystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba) object in the sub-function.

Alternatively, you can store all the filenames in the main function into an `Array` to loop thru instead of nesting your `Dir` functions like this:

```
  Dim sFiles() as String
  Dim sFilename as String
  ReDim sFiles(0)
  sFilename = Dir(myPath & "*CITIES*.xls")
  Do Until sFilename = ""
    ReDim Preserve sFiles(UBound(sFiles) + 1)
    sFiles(UBound(sFiles)) = sFilename
    sFilename = Dir()
  Loop
```

Then you have found all your CITIES in a 1 based `Array` to loop thru.