# Convert symbols in MS Word

Tags: vba, encoding, ms-word

I have documents written in old Kazakh font (Kazakhstan), using win98. Nowadays we are using Times New Roman, but this font shows strange unicode characters. I can use substitution (Ctrl + H) to change all symbols to Times New Roman encoding, but we have 42 (84 in both cases) letters.

For example I have all symbols from old font in first line, and all symbols from new font at the second line in the same order.

Can someone write an example script that will read this two lines char by char, making something like a dictionary in Java then do a global substitution.

**Update**

Thanks Roman Plischke!

I wrote a macro that recursively applies to all *.doc files in some folder.

```
Sub Substitution()
'
' Substitution of the chars from font Times/Kazakh
' to Times New Roman
' Chars to substitute are 176-255 bytes, 73 and 105 byte
Dim sTab As String
    sTab = "£ª½¥¡¯Ž¼º¾´¢¿žÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ"
    Selection.Find.Font.Shadow = False
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Shadow = False
    For i = 1 To Len(sTab)
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ChrW(i + 175)
        .Replacement.Text = Mid(sTab, i, 1)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Find.Text = Selection.Find.Text
    Next i
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ChrW(105)
        .Replacement.Text = "³"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Find.Text = Selection.Find.Text

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ChrW(73)
        .Replacement.Text = "²"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Find.Text = Selection.Find.Text

    ' kazakh language
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.LanguageID = WdLanguageID.wdKazakh
    Application.CheckLanguage = False
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
End Sub

    ' Function that Call Substitution() for all documents
    ' in folder vDirectory
Sub LoopDirectory()
    Dim vDirectory As String
    Dim oDoc As Document

    vDirectory = "E:\soft\Dedushka\not\"

    vFile = Dir(vDirectory & "*.doc")

    Do While vFile <> ""
    Set oDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=vDirectory & vFile)

    Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name + " Started"
    Call Zamena
    Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name + " Finish"

    oDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True
    vFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used for similar conversions this subroutine. The "heart" of code is a definition of string *sTab*. This string contains all charactesr for code 127 and above. Fill this string by new characters one by one.

If you have a code table of the old Kazakh coding, it is very simple: type in the VBA editor all characters starting 127 char. VBA editor works in Unicode, so this works.

If you have not a code table, you have to get an old code of each character (try select this character and press Alt+X) and write it manually in the string at right position.

In both cases, for unused (or unusually) character you may fill a space or other character.

The rest of code replaces each character with code above 127 for new character from *sTab*.

```
Sub Convert()
    Dim sTab As String
    Dim sKod As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ch As String

    'new chars 127-255:
    'note: for each character above 127 fill in this table unicode character
    sTab = "ÄÃãÉ¥ÖÜá¹ÈäèÆæéŸÏí“”ëEóeôöoúÌìü†°Ê£§•¶ß®©™ê¨‡gIlÎ__îK__³Ll¼¾ÅåNnÑ¬VñÒ_«»… òÕOõO–—“”‘’÷_OÀàØ‹›øRrŠ‚„šŒœÁÍŽžUÓÔuÙÚùÛûUuÝýk¯£¿G¡"

    'clear all shadow - we use this attrib as flag for changed characters
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Shadow = True
    Selection.Find.replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.replacement.Font.Shadow = False
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    'changing characters by codetable
    Selection.Find.Font.Shadow = False
    Selection.Find.replacement.Font.Shadow = True
    For i = 1 To Len(sTab)
        With Selection.Find
            ch = Chr(126 + i)
            If ch = "^" Then ch = "^^"
            .Text = ch
            ch = Mid(sTab, i, 1)
            If ch = "^" Then ch = "^^"
            .replacement.Text = ch
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Selection.Find.Text = Selection.Find.Text
    Next i
    'clear shadows
    Selection.Find.Font.Shadow = True
    Selection.Find.replacement.Font.Shadow = False
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    ' kazakh language
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.LanguageID = WdLanguageID.wdKazakh
    Application.CheckLanguage = False
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you explain a few things please.

sTab should be filled by characters from old font?
`Selection.LanguageID = WdLanguageID.wdKazakh`
what is wdKazakh? It is name of font?
( full name of old font is Times/Kazakh )

Comment: `Selection.LanguageID = WdLanguageID.wdKazakh` tags selected text (whole text in this case) as Kazakh language. It is not necessary, word it uses for spell checking etc.

Comment: Can you help me to run this macro for all *.doc files in some folder, recursively?

Comment: Search _vba recursively list files_ or something similar at Google or Stack overflow, there are tons of examples. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/729844/2369384) is one. For each file open document, convert, save as new document. For tens of documents I would do it manually, for hundreds of documents I would make a macro.