# How to recursively move through Excel files in a given folder and update all workbook connection instances in a file

Tags: vba, excel, recursion

So I have this code for now that loops through files in a directory and corrects the OLEDB connection string and text.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

FolderName = "C:\Files\"
If Right(FolderName, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then FolderName = FolderName & Application.PathSeparator
Fname = Dir(FolderName & "*.xls")

'loop through the files
Do While Len(Fname)

    With Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Fname)

            With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MYCONNECTION").OLEDBConnection
                .CommandText = Array("NEWNAME")
                .CommandType = xlCmdCube
                .Connection = Array( _
                "OLEDB;Provider=MSOLAP.5;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=MyCube;Data Source=server.domain.net\OLAP;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Update Isolation Level=2" _
                )
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
                .SavePassword = False
                .SourceConnectionFile = ""
                .MaxDrillthroughRecords = 1000
                .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
                .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
                .RetrieveInOfficeUILang = True
            End With
            With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MYCONNECTION")
                .Name = "MYCONNECTION"
                .Description = ""
            End With
                ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With

    ' go to the next file in the folder
    Fname = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

I would like to upgrade this so that it would recursively scan through the given directory and correct all .xls files that are found even in subdirectories.

And additionaly I would like that it checks workbook connections, because many files will have many instances od the connection (eg. MYCONNECTION, MYCONNECTION1, MYCONNECTION2, MYCONNECTION3,...) and it would need to correct the same OLEDB string and text name to all instances of thw workbook connection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: look at the FileSystemObject.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `dir` in a recursiv way. Use `fileSystemObject` instead. There is a good VB6 example on [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729844/7599798), should work also with VBA (add the `Microsoft scripting Runtime` as Reference)